# Thermistor - Steinhart-Hart Coefficients

Tags: electrical-engineering, sensors, measurements, temperature, calibration

In order to identify [Steinhart-Hart coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhart%E2%80%93Hart_equation) for a thermistor, three known temperatures may be used to find three resistances.

What is the best way to choose these temperatures to calibrate from?

Is it more beneficial to use three temperatures within the typical operating temperature of the thermistor, or to take a broad range of temperatures (say 0, 50, and 100°C)?

Comment: The Steinhart-Hart coefficients are usually published on the thermistor data sheet with tolerances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends to some extent. Normally you'd assume you should look at the datasheet, see what it's operating limits are and then use the centre point for your 3 points. If the thermistor is not entirely linear however, you'll be off at certain temperatures across the range. Personally i'd find out what my expected limits are for the application and calibrate for those limits. I'd even take more than 3 points for that reason.

Comment: calibrate for the range you need ie focus the accuracy...